# Borel rank of certain automorphism orbits in $L_p$ lattices

Tags: borel-sets, banach-lattices

For any $p$ with $1\leq p < \infty$, let $L_p([0,1])$ be the Banach lattice of $L_p$ functions on the unit interval (with the standard measure). Let $A=\{f\in L_p([0,1]):\left\lVert f \right \rVert_p = 1,f\geq 0\}$, where $f\geq 0$ is understood in the sense of the lattice operation, i.e. $f\vee 0 = f$. This is clearly a closed set in the norm topology on $L_p([0,1])$.

My understanding is that there are precisely 2 automorphism types (in the sense of Banach lattice automorphisms) of elements of $A$, specifically $B=\{f\in A:(\exists g \in A)f\wedge g = 0\}$ and $C=\{f\in A:(\forall g\in A)f\wedge g\neq 0\}$. It seems that these should be analytic sets since $\text{Aut}(L_p([0,1]))$ can be given a Polish group structure and $B$ and $C$ are continuous images of $\text{Aut}(L_p([0,1]))$. So by Lusin's separation theorem and the fact that $A$ is closed we get that $B$ and $C$ are Borel sets.

Assuming I'm right that they are Borel sets, what are their ranks?

Comment: I might be having a stupid moment, but: could you explain why $C$ is analytic in more detail?

Comment: IIRC you can put a Polish group structure on $\text{Aut}(L_p([0,1]))$ with the property that the application map $L_p([0,1])\times \text{Aut}(L_p([0,1])) \rightarrow L_p([0,1])$ is continuous. For any given $f \in L_p([0,1])$, the map $g \mapsto g(f)$ should be continuous and so the orbit of a given element is the continuous image of $\text{Aut}(L_p([0,1]))$, and hence analytic.